# How to pass and array and modify it in a function in postgres

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, stored-functions

I am trying to write a function that does this: basically create an array with same data elements as the array that is passed to the function but with some change sometimes - like if some element is even then the flag should change from N to Y. The procedure takes as input an array that has two elements - a number and a flag. eg. (1,'N'), (2,'N'). Now if the passed number is even then the proc should modify that value and change to (2,'Y') whereas the other one remains as (1,'N').

Basically my array basics are not clear and reading through details has not helped so this question.

I tried the following but it is not working...can you please suggest:

```
CREATE TYPE test_n_t_num AS (
v_n double precision,
is_even character varying(1));

create function temp_n_proc_2(p_nums IN OUT test_n_t_num[])
as
$$
declare
   v_nums test_n_t_num[];
     v_cnt double precision;
BEGIN
  v_cnt := cardinality(p_nums);

   v_nums := ARRAY[]::test_n_t_num[];

  for i in 1..v_cnt LOOP
   if p_nums[i].v_n_double % 2 = 0 then
      v_nums [i].is_even := 'Y';
      p_nums [i].is_even := 'Y'
   else 
      v_nums [i].is_even := p_nums [i].is_even;
   end if;

   v_nums[i] := {p_nums[i].v_n,v_nums [i].is_even};  

  END LOOP;

END;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Also later I need to loop through and print out the values in the array v_nums - one that is defined in the function.

Thank you,
Nirav

Comment: Well I can't even create this on my system, it doesn't like the syntax of the function. But anyway, your return value is `p_nums`, but most of your assignments are to `v_nums`... is that correct?

Comment: yes I just want to have v_nums set up too (in my actual work issue which I am modeling by this question, I need to print out that v_nums) . And I am very much messed up on the syntax. And also I am editing p_nums too once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue when I was trying to do this sort of thing back in the day. Basically you can't assign to composite objects using array notation, i.e. `your_array[1].field := value` doesn't work. Here's something that does (I don't use `cardinality` since I'm still on 9.3 and that was added in 9.4):

```
CREATE TYPE public.test1 AS (a INTEGER, is_even BOOLEAN);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f1(ar INOUT public.test1[]) AS $$
DECLARE
        t public.test1;
BEGIN
        RAISE NOTICE '%', ar;
        FOR i IN 1..ARRAY_LENGTH(ar, 1) LOOP
                t := ar[i];
                t.is_even := t.a % 2 = 0;
                ar[i] := t;
        END LOOP;
        RAISE NOTICE '%', ar;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

So basically create a variable of that type, read the indexed item into the variable, modify the fields, then copy the variable's content back to the array.

`SELECT * FROM f1('{"(1,)","(4,)","(6,)"}'::public.test1[])` returns `{"(1,f)","(4,t)","(6,t)"}`

The messages printed (this is using pgadmin 3) are:

```
NOTICE:  {"(1,)","(4,)","(6,)"}
NOTICE:  {"(1,f)","(4,t)","(6,t)"}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Eurotrash!  I have not seen anywhere in documentation where this details are pointed out. This is tricky!  One more question. What if in the function I want to print out the original array that was passed and the revised array. Is that possible?

Comment: @dbusern Not sure if I understand what you mean by print - see edit above, is that it? Since the same array variable is used for input and output, to print the original version I need to call RAISE NOTICE at the start, before any modifications are done. Then at the end before it returns, it again prints the modified array.

Comment: Hi Eurotrash, I got your point. My bad. What I should say is; Application needs to be returned with the revised array. I think you have already provided details. i wll test out and confirm by tomorrow if that works out. Thanks again.

Comment: @ Eurotrash. Can't thank you enough. It worked Exactly as you said and completely solved my issue. This is such a very excellent help. Thank you!!!!